# Get the Image url and username from Firebase and show into Textview and Imageview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter

I have one `BlogActivity` where it has profile image placeholder, username placeholder where I have used Recycle Adapter to populate each with user imge and name.

I created Second activity where it has one `ImageView` and `TextView` with id `user_image` and `user_name`.

How can I get the current `user_image` and current `user_name` to show in my Second activity?

The Recycle adapter for Blog activity is

```html
public class BlogRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BlogRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<BlogPost> blog_list;
    public Context context;

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private PopupWindow popWindow;

    public BlogRecyclerAdapter(List<BlogPost> blog_list){

        this.blog_list = blog_list;


    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.blog_list_item, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        final String blogPostId = blog_list.get(position).BlogPostId;
        final String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        String desc_data = blog_list.get(position).getDesc();
        holder.setDescText(desc_data);

        String image_url = blog_list.get(position).getImage_url();
        String thumbUri = blog_list.get(position).getImage_thumb();
        holder.setBlogImage(image_url, thumbUri);

        String user_id = blog_list.get(position).getUser_id();
        //User Data will be retrieved here...



        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(user_id).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    String userName = task.getResult().getString("name");
                    String userImage = task.getResult().getString("image");

                    holder.setUserData(userName, userImage);


                } else {

                    //Firebase Exception

                }

            }
        });




    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return blog_list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View mView;
        private TextView blogUserName;
        private CircleImageView blogUserImage;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

            blogLikeBtn = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_like_btn);
            blogCommentBtn = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_comment_icon);

        }


        public void setUserData(final String name, final String image) {
            blogUserImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_image);
            blogUserName = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_name);

            blogUserName.setText(name);

            RequestOptions placeholderOption = new RequestOptions();
            placeholderOption.placeholder(R.drawable.profile_placeholder);

            if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
                Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderOption).load(image).into(blogUserImage);
            }

            mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("user_name", name);
                    intent.putExtra("user_image", image);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }



        public void updateLikesCount(int count){

            blogLikeCount = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_like_count);
            blogLikeCount.setText(count + " Likes");

        }

    }



}
```

**My second activity is**

```html
        final String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name");

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You're Offline!"+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But here it throws error in `name` in Second activity and I couldn't resolve.

Please kindly suggest on how to get the `user_image` and `user_name` from used in Recycle adapter to any other activity `TextView` and `ImageView`

Below I have My Firebase structure image

[image: Firebase Structure]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseFirestore  db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Users").document(currentUserId);
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d("check logcat", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
            } else {
                Log.d("", "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("", "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

here is doc : https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: here is the error I'm getting when I paste your code in my Second Activity  https://ibb.co/mGBTMn

Comment: @HrithikRawal CHECK UPDATED ANSWER

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you just have to pass the user name and the image to the second activity that you set using `setUserData` function. So you just have to get an `onClick` method in your adapter which handles the passing data between your first activity to second activity. I hope you are fetching the data from your firebase database perfectly in your first activity.

```
public void setUserData(String name, String image) {
    blogUserImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_image);
    blogUserName = mView.findViewById(R.id.blog_user_name);

    blogUserName.setText(name);

    RequestOptions placeholderOption = new RequestOptions();
    placeholderOption.placeholder(R.drawable.profile_placeholder);

    if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing()) {
        Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(placeholderOption).load(image).into(blogUserImage);
    }

    mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("user_name", name);
                intent.putExtra("user_image", image);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}
```

Then in your `MainActivity`, just get the extras from your intent and show it in desired positions.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name");
    String image = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_image");

    // Use the name and image to show this is in respective TextView and ImageView
}
```

Comment: this is exactly how I wanted the solution. I implemented your method in myy Recycle adapter but I'm getting error on putStringExtra, How can I resolve this. Here is the image file https://ibb.co/cLddnS

Comment: Sorry, just use `putExtra` instead of `putStringExtra`. See the edited code. Thanks.

Comment: when I replace String name = getIntent().getExtra("user_name"); instead of String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name"); in Adapter..it solves the problem but now when I use   String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name"); in Mainactivity will it get the extras value..shouldn't I use   String name = getIntent().getExtra("user_name"); in Mainactivity ....and when I did that I got the following error https://ibb.co/kqtNE7

Comment: No, you can use `getStringExtra` in your `MainActivity` as stated above.

Comment: gradle build is still compiling....I'll comment the result...Hope it works. finger crossed.

Comment: It returns null on which point. Can you please post the logcat?

Comment: @Raez what I actually did was in my next activity, I used the below code  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Logged in as!"+name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); and when I compiled and run it returned Logged in as !null .

Comment: Can you please update the adapter code in your question that you currently have?

Comment: The code looks okay. I am now confused why are you getting null. Please check if the `name` and the `image` has correct value.